# Iterate over rows and calculate mean of selected items putting the new value in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Using Pandas I have a data frame with rows and columns:

```
id  column1 column2 column3
1         4  Banana       2
2         4  Carrot       
3         1  Tomato       3
4         7   Melon       5
5         1    Lime       5
```

I want to iterate through each row and calculate the mean the items in column1 and column2 (e.g. Row 1: 4+2/2=3). Everything will be put in a new column called mean. empty values should be ignored.

The result should be like:

```
id  column1 column2 column3  mean
1         4  Banana       2     3
2         4  Carrot             4
3         1  Tomato       3     2
4         7   Melon       5     6
5         2    Lime       5   3.5
```

Comment: Use `df['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['mean'] = df[['column1', 'column3']].mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: just a suggestion... ```select dtypes``` could help avoid the hardcoding of the column names

Comment: @sammywemmy - For me pandas omit non numeric columns, so working `df['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)`

Comment: nice. even better.